# Parsing Log file for specific values

Tags: r, parsing

I am trying to parse many log files for specific values. What I am doing is opening the file, and then grabbing the data that is necessary to me. Then I would want to write the specific data in a text file that will be used for further analysis. 
Here is what I am doing at first:

```
#Select Copy From Dir, Change \\ to /
copyfrom<-gsub("\\\\","/",choose.dir(default = "", caption = "Select folder you wish to copy files from"))
#File names
listfiles<-list.files(copyfrom)
#Total amount of files
totalfiles=length(listfiles)
```

This means that total files will be a list of all the files from the directory that I choose (One that contains the log files).
Then using listfiles[1], I can open a particular file. For this example lets just focus on 1 file but in my script I will be looping to read all the files.
Next I would want to open a connection with that file and read all the values.

```
 con <- file(paste0(copyfrom,"/",listfiles[totalfiles]))
  #open connection to file
  open(con); 
  #read file
  read <- readLines(con)
```

When I do that I get this:

```
> read
[1] "batch_name\tquant_id\tinstrument\tstandard_r_squared\tstandard_intercept\tstandard_slope\tmedian_ccn_pg_ul\tqc_status\tqc_reason\tinitiated"
[2] "B01042016_1\t79741\t1\t0.9986341\t-0.057213258\t0.966673255\t31.4047947\tpass\t\t2016-04-01T13:55:57+02:00"
```

In that log file there are two rows. One row is represented by [1] and the other by [2]. From there I open just line 2 (thats all im interested in) by

```
> read[2]
[1] "B01042016_1\t79741\t1\t0.9986341\t-0.057213258\t0.966673255\t31.4047947\tpass\t\t2016-04-01T13:55:57+02:00"
```

Okay this is where I am stuck. I need to grab 3 values from this string. One will be t0.9986341 and the other will be t\t2016-04-01T13:55:57+02:00. The first value represents some calculation and the other is the date. What I want is that those two numbers are pasted in some text file. For now pasted into a variable will be fine. I am having a hard time splitting that string of characters.
I want to know how to identfy a particular value in that string, for t0.9986341, I tried read[2,1] but it didnt work. Any other suggestions. Sorry if this is long but I rather be complete in my thinking to express the issue. Thanks.

Comment: If the files are tab separated with column headers why would you use `readLines`? Is there something about the structure of the log files that you haven't told us?

Comment: the \t is a special character for "tabulation", you may indeed import data in a structured way with `read.table` using `sep="\t"` as option. In case your log does not have a tabular structure, you may have a look at `strsplit`